# Pandas Dataframe iterrows alternative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below code to loop the `DataFrame` and update the column value. This code works but giving warning message.  looking alternate way of doing the same operation.

```
  for i, row in df3.iterrows():    
    if is_match_found(row):
        df3.at[i, 'Match 2'] = "Yes"
```

**Warning message:**

> FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future
> version. Use .items instead.   for item in s.iteritems():

**Update 1**

I have created new code for testing. on this one not getting the warning message. let me re-test my application and watch for the warning message.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["James", "White", "John"],
                   'rebounds': [7, 7, 8]})

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'rebounds'] = row['rebounds'] + 2

print(df)
```

Comment: what is is_match_found()? what it does? essentially the functionality under it. post the code for it

Comment: The waring itself seems suggest you to use `for item in s.items()`. Given your particular problem you could avoid the loop and use `np.where`

Comment: Could you post a solution using np.where @rpanai, I would be interested in a solution avoiding a loop. (I was thinking of the apply method but it is basically a loop as well)

Comment: @robinood please post a specific problem following this guid [mcve]

Comment: @rpanai I am not the author of this question, only a curious guy :)

Comment: @robinood in my profile there is a link to linkedin. Feel free to drop me a message

Answer (score 0):

Initially my code was:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
       key = row['key']
```

I translated to the following and the warning went away:

```
    for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
       index = row.Index
       key = row.key
```

from an article I stumbled to to his is also consistently much faster